# Rails 3 CanCan Authorizing Scoped Ownership

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan, before-filter

I'm building a school systems where instructors can manage classrooms in scope of their respective schools.

I have the following ability setup to match:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  #define the user ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)    
    if user.has_role? :instructor
      can :manage, Classroom do |classroom|
        classroom.new_record? && classroom.school_id == user.school_id || classroom.instructor == user
      end
    end
  end 

end
```

In theory this should enable instructors to manage new records which won't have their relationship with the instructor setup so long as both the instructor and the new classroom belong to the same school.

In my classroom new action I build the classroom from the parent School to accommodate this `@classroom = @school.classrooms.build`. This initializes the new Classroom record with a school_id enabling the instructor to to thereby manage the record. However in my classrooms controller I call `load_and_authorize_resource` which authorizes the instructor before the school to classroom relationship gets established and a CanCan authorization exception is thrown.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CanCan is probably checking abilities before the association with the school is built. You could break out the create and manage permissions explicitly:

```
can :create, Classroom
can :manage, Classroom, instructor_id: user.id
```

and then check that the classroom belongs to the instructor's school in a validation.

Comment: Of course, I guess I was being a little over-reliant on cancan for my authorization. One thing to note though is the syntax `can :manage, Classroom, instructor == user` doesn't quite seem to work on cancan 1.6.8, I `get undefined local variable or method instructor`. Works fine inside of a classroom do block however.

Comment: That syntax might only work with attributes, not associations - try the edited version.

Comment: Nice try but still no dice. Being a little more verbose isn't a huge issue though.

Comment: Bleh, my bad. Fixing it again - it takes hashes of conditions, not boolean expressions. See the "Hashed of conditions" section of the [wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities) for details.